JS puppeeter - changin IP by proxy
I'm working on a Node.js project where I’m trying to change my IP address using proxies with Puppeteer. However, when I open the Chromium browser window (in script), I still see my original IP address instead of the proxy IP. I’m relatively new to this, so any advice on how to properly configure the proxy would be greatly appreciated.
Here's a simplified version of my code: ( some npm packages: )
antibotbrowser
puppeteer-extra
puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth

async function switchProxy(proxies) { 
    while (!testPassed && proxies.length > 0) {
        proxy = proxies[Math.floor(Math.random() * proxies.length)];
        testPassed = await testProxyConnection(proxy);
    }
    return proxy;
}

async function testProxyConnection(proxy) {
    try {
        const protocol = proxy.protocol === 2 ? 'https' : 'http';
        
        const response = await axios.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', {
            proxy: {
                host: proxy.ip,
                port: proxy.port,
                protocol: protocol
            },
            timeout: 10000
        });

        const originIP = response.data.origin; 

        return true;
    } 
}

async function createBrowserWithProxyAndAntibot(proxy) {
    puppeteer.use(puppeteerExtraPluginStealth());
    const antibrowser = await antibotbrowser.startbrowser();

    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
        browserWSEndpoint: antibrowser.websokcet,
        args: [
            --proxy-server=${proxy.protocol === 2 ? 'https' : 'http'}://${proxy.ip}:${proxy.port},
            '--disable-features=site-per-process',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        ],
        headless: false,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // CHECK IP - this print proxy IP
    const checkIP = await page.goto('https://httpbin.org/ip');
    const ipResult = await checkIP.json();
    console.log(Page IP: ${ipResult.origin});

    return { browser, page };
} 


(async () => {
    const proxies = await fetchProxiesFromAPI();
    const proxy = await switchProxy(proxies);  // Vyberte jeden funkční proxy

    const { browser, page } = await createBrowserWithProxyAndAntibot(proxy);

})();

I tried different proxy servers (free), modification of settings..

What's fetchProxiesFromAPI? Please share a [mcve]. Thanks.
